# static const data member vs hard-coded value in function

Tags: c++

I have a class with a data attribute, say of type `int`, which should be constant throughout the run of the program, and have the same value in all class instances.  I want this value to be accessable through a public member function called `get_value()`.  The obvious way to do this is to define a private `static const` class member and have `get_value` return it.

Alternatively, I could just place the value in the definition of `get_value` itself: for example,  `int get_value()const{return 5;}`.  Is the first method obviously better than the second?

Comment: Public static constants could also be a consideration. Like `std::numeric_limits<int>::digits`.

Comment: You mention in an answer that get_value needs to be virtual, yet in the problem statement, you say that get_value needs to have all class instances return the same thing.  The whole reason to make a function virtual is to make it do something different depending on the class instance.  I think you may need to rethink what you are using this for.

Comment: one curiosity is if the static-in-function (possibly inlined thus header-able) pattern circumvents the need for a (additional file thus additional compile and linker time) implmentation file defining a static member's storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a computational point of view there shouldn't be much differences in term of compiled code.

But with the first method your are not hiding variable inside your function : if you have not 1 but 10 of these variable I would expect to see them defined at the begin of your class, not inside some getter functions 10's of lines below.

I consider it cleaner, I know what are "magic values" by looking at your class, I don't have to go through your functions.

Comment: I guessed that computationally the two would be similar, so I was really asking about style.  The value needs to be accessed through a public method (which a client would want to know about), and could be defined in the class body where the client can see it.  It just seems to me that using a function and a static member I'm adding extra code that isn't needed.

Comment: When I'm looking for constants/hard-coded variables/magic variables in code files I will look at : the top of the file / the top of classes definitions. Looking into functions definitions wouldn't be natural. It's extra code, but easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Think about a maintenance programmer who looks at your code a year from now and thinks: why five? What does five mean? Maybe it's really six when we work on Saturdays?

Compare his task if he sees this instead:

```
   int const MY_BEST_GUESS_AT_LOW_WATERMARK = 5;
   return MY_BEST_GUESS_AT_LOW_WATERMARK;
```

Comment: I simplified the function name for illustration- it reality it has a more descriptive name.  The comparison really is between a function and a static variable (both with descriptive names), or just the function

Comment: My point stands, go for readability. Compiler will generate the same code, since your values are known at compile time. If you think your constant values are part of the *interface* of your class (i.e. your class says "this parameter defaults to 5" to the world), define them in the class body. If you consider them implementation details, subject to change without notice, hide them in the implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is just matter of style as the compile will optimise the const away in most cases.

Comment: Is one style generally preferred?

Comment: I like the less is more approach these days. The less code there is, the less to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just declare your static constant as public as follows?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  static const int VALUE = 5;
};

int main() {
  cout << Foo::VALUE << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You could of course then add a public member `get_value` but I don't know what that would give you. I don't believe that this breaks encapsulation since `VALUE` is a constant: I would *not* expose a static or member *variable* in this way but it seems reasonable for a constant and there is some precedent for this in the C++ standard library.

Comment: `public` data members reduce encapsulation. They are avoided as long as possible.

Comment: @stw: Good reason. +1. Actually, this is an important thing to add to the problem statement. If this method has to be virtual this prevents some of the more obvious compiler optimizations from being possible (inlining etc.)

Comment: Would that then favour one method over the other?

Comment: On second thought, probably not - though somebody who's smarter than me might be able to comment further. I suspect that the compiler would inline the integer constant into the body of the `get_value` method regardless. However, the call to `get_value` could not itself be inlined in some cases since it's virtual.